# new dataset is not accepted by chartj template

Tags: javascript, html, css, chart.js, node-red

I am trying to plot a line chart on the node red dashboard.
This template creates the desired scrollable chart with 100 randomly generated datapoints:

```
<style>.chartWrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.chartWrapper > canvas {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.chartAreaWrapper {
  width: auto;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
</style>

<div class="chartWrapper">
  <div class="chartAreaWrapper">
  <div class="chartAreaWrapper2">
      <canvas id="chart-Test" height="351" width="4000"></canvas>
  </div>
  </div>
  <canvas id="axis-Test" height="351" width="0"></canvas>
</div>

<script>
    
$(document).ready(function () {

    function generateLabels() {
        var chartLabels = [];
        for (x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
            chartLabels.push(x);
        }
        return chartLabels;
    }

   function generateData() {
        var chartData = [];
        for (x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
            chartData.push(Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1));
        }
        return chartData;
    }
    

    function addData(numData, chart) {
        for (var i = 0; i < numData; i++) {
            chart.data.datasets[0].data.push(Math.random() * 100);
            chart.data.labels.push("Label" + i);
            var newwidth = $('.chartAreaWrapper2').width() + 60;
            $('.chartAreaWrapper2').width(newwidth);
        }
    }

    var chartData = {
        labels: generateLabels(),
        datasets: [{
            label: "Test Data Set",
            data: generateData(),
            pointRadius: 0,
            borderColor: "#4ED7FC",
            borderWidth: 2,
            fill: false
        }]
    };



    $(function () {
        var rectangleSet = false;

        var canvasTest = $('#chart-Test');
        var chartTest = new Chart(canvasTest, {
            type: 'line',
            data: chartData,
            
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
            responsive: true,
            
        });
        addData(5, chartTest);
    });
});    
</script>
```

[image: chart1]

Next I wanted to replace the generated datapoints with a payload message coming into the dashboard template node, where `msg.payload[0].data` is an `array[2500]`.
I thought I would be able to achieve this by replacing `generateData()`like so:

```
<style>.chartWrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.chartWrapper > canvas {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.chartAreaWrapper {
  width: auto;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
</style>

<div class="chartWrapper">
  <div class="chartAreaWrapper">
  <div class="chartAreaWrapper2">
      <canvas id="chart-Test" height="351" width="4000"></canvas>
  </div>
  </div>
  <canvas id="axis-Test" height="351" width="0"></canvas>
</div>

<script>
    
$(document).ready(function () {

    function generateLabels() {
        var chartLabels = [];
        for (x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
            chartLabels.push(x);
        }
        return chartLabels;
    }

    /*function generateData() {
        var chartData = [];
        for (x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
            chartData.push(Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1));
        }
        return chartData;
    }*/
    function generateData(msg) {
        var chartData = [];
        chartData = msg.payload[0].data;        
        return chartData;
    }
    

    function addData(numData, chart) {
        for (var i = 0; i < numData; i++) {
            chart.data.datasets[0].data.push(Math.random() * 100);
            chart.data.labels.push("Label" + i);
            var newwidth = $('.chartAreaWrapper2').width() + 60;
            $('.chartAreaWrapper2').width(newwidth);
        }
    }

    var chartData = {
        labels: generateLabels(),
        datasets: [{
            label: "Test Data Set",
            data: generateData(),
            pointRadius: 0,
            borderColor: "#4ED7FC",
            borderWidth: 2,
            fill: false
        }]
    };



    $(function () {
        var rectangleSet = false;

        var canvasTest = $('#chart-Test');
        var chartTest = new Chart(canvasTest, {
            type: 'line',
            data: chartData,
            
            
            responsive: true,
            options: {
                maintainAspectRatio: false,
                tooltips: {
                    titleFontSize: 0,
                    titleMarginBottom: 0,
                    bodyFontSize: 12
                },
                legend: {
                    display: false
                },
                scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            fontSize: 12,
                            display: false
                        }
                    }],
                    yAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            fontSize: 12,
                            beginAtZero: true
                        }
                    }]
                },
            }
        });
        addData(5, chartTest);
    });
});    
</script>
```

But then the chart is just showing a blank:
[image]

Why is that?

[edit]

the incoming payload is not empty:
[image]

Comment: please confirm that you are receiving values in your `array[2500]` and the charjs version that you are using

Comment: There is no `msg` object in the browser when the code from the template gets executed... You need to remember that all the template does is render some text that is then sent to the browser to run.

Comment: @hardlib only understood your comment now. Found the documentation that explains how to get a msg object in the script section of the node. posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the dashboard template node does not easily accept payload messages on the script section.
[watch function](https://flows.nodered.org/flow/2f1aaf0635f9bf23207152682323240a)
I have to use something like:

```
// Watch the payload and update
(function(scope) {
    scope.$watch('msg.payload', function(data) {
        update(data);
    });
})(scope);

function update(dta) {
    theScope.send({payload:dta});
    bleh = dta.name;
    otherStuff();
}
```

to watch a incoming payload and store it.

My initial question "Why is that?" is therefore answered.
Unfortunately I am not quite sure how to implement this new bit of code to the array coming in in msg.payload[0.data in my specific case.

Answer (score 0):

I would try the follwing:

1.- Check that your `array[2500]` has values between 1 and 100 and pass in the first 100 instead the whole 2500 array to check if that works

2.- Might depend on the chartjs version, but I would try to put the maintainAspectRatio property inside an `options: {}` object. See below.

```
var chart = new Chart('blabla', {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {},
  options: {
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
  }
});
```

Apart from that, 2500 records seems to be a too big amount of data to handle. If the graph renders for smaller amounts, I would try to keep the graph drawn with an amount that gets rendered, and the fetch the data + update the chart depending on the users x-scroll.

Edit:

I think you need to call the `addData` for your new array with a modified addData function that would look something like this, for the width to fit.

```
function addData(chart) {
    for (var i = 0; i < chart.data[0].data.length; i++) {
        //chart.data.datasets[0].data.push(Math.random() * 100);
        //chart.data.labels.push("Label" + i);
        var newwidth = $('.chartAreaWrapper2').width() + 60;
        $('.chartAreaWrapper2').width(newwidth);
    }
}
```

Note that your script work up determined num of records with the arrangements mentioned, so if the graph goes blank can only be that your new array is empty or has some issue.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>.chartWrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.chartWrapper > canvas {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.chartAreaWrapper {
  width: auto;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
</style>

<div class="chartWrapper">
  <div class="chartAreaWrapper">
  <div class="chartAreaWrapper2">
      <canvas id="chart-Test" height="300" width="1200"></canvas>
  </div>
  </div>
  <canvas id="axis-Test" height="300" width="0"></canvas>

<div class="chartWrapper">
  <div class="chartAreaWrapper">
    <div class="chartAreaWrapper2">
      <canvas id="chart-Test" height="351" width="4000"></canvas>
    </div>
  </div>
  <canvas id="axis-Test" height="351" width="0"></canvas>
</div>

<script>
    
$(document).ready(function () {
    function generateLabels() {
        var chartLabels = [];
        for (x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
            chartLabels.push(x);
        }
        return chartLabels;
    }

   function generateData() {
        var chartData = [];
        for (x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
            chartData.push(Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1));
        }
        return chartData;
    }
    
    function addData(numData, chart) {
        for (var i = 0; i < numData; i++) {
            chart.data.datasets[0].data.push(Math.random() * 100);
            chart.data.labels.push("Label" + i);
            var newwidth = $('.chartAreaWrapper2').width() + 60;
            $('.chartAreaWrapper2').width(newwidth);
        }
    }

    var chartData = {
        labels: generateLabels(),
        datasets: [{
            label: "Test Data Set",
            data: generateData(),
            pointRadius: 0,
            borderColor: "#4ED7FC",
            borderWidth: 2,
            fill: false
        }]
    };

    $(function () {
        var rectangleSet = false;
        var canvasTest = $('#chart-Test');
        var chartTest = new Chart(canvasTest, {
            type: 'line',
            data: chartData,
            options: {
                maintainAspectRatio: false,
                responsive: true
            }
        });
        addData(300, chartTest);
    });
});    
</script>
```

Comment: I caped `payload[0].data` at 100 entries now. But it's still showing a blank chart.
I also moved `maintainAspectRatio` to options as well. I did have some odd aspect ratio behavior earlier, so this probably fixed that.

I also first initialized the array in `generateData()` (updated question), but that too had no effect.

Is there something else in the template I used I am overseeing? there also is `addData()` that I dont understand the purpose for and it also seems to generate random numbers. could the problem lay elsewhere?

Comment: `addData` pushes de data into the dataset array and arranges the width of the `chartAreaWrapper2` element for each record pushed into the array for the chart to fit. Do you have records in `payload[0].data` if you put a breakpoint or do a `console.log()`?

Comment: if for your array substitution you are changing the question code, please post the code that does not work, not the one that works. If you are using the one in the question, I think it can be that your array is empty. See updated question

Comment: just edited the question to show entire new (not working) code

Comment: one sec. ill show that the payload is not empty as well

Comment: you need to adjust the with with `$('.chartAreaWrapper2').width(newwidth);`

Comment: with the `generateData()` funtion, the first 100 records are created. That 100 record array is passed in to the chart with the first 100 values. Then the `addData()` adds records and adjusts the width for each record added, adding a with to the default one for each record added

Comment: you need to apply that logic for your new array. Check if with the default html width it works for 100 records, and from there you can adjust the with dynamically as in the working example

Comment: ok I understand now that this template may not be 100% ideal for my use then. But its the only one I found to horizontal scroll a chart. I was hoping that I can simply feed it my payload and then it would horizontally scroll. I tried removing `addData` from the script in the hopes that I can then simply feed my payload into  `generateData`and it would show the chart with my own payload. But that completely breakes the entire script. Do you see a way to remove the `addData` feature so the script will simply accept my payload?